# CURL web pages to database inserting duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, curl

I'm writing a PHP script to fetch website content and insert each web page into a separate post in my MySQL table. My method of choice is cURL, some regular expressions, preg_match_all, a couple of foreach loops and finally the MySQL query. The code is fine, so I won't post it here.

The problem is that the script works fine with less than about 200 posts being inserted to the database, but when the number exceeds ~200 the browser never stops loading. I want to store exactly 749 web pages (the content of each page is plain text). When I press stop and look at the database, I have around 2 000 posts in the database and around 5 duplicates of each post.

So, the conclusion I draw is that there's something (browser, server, database?) that can't handle that many pages, aborts the process and restarts it. I have tried increasing the max execution time in PHP and likewise for cURL but with the same result.

Here's a previous post where I hade some problems earlier in the process. [Content from large number of web pages into array (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953064/content-from-large-number-of-web-pages-into-array-php)

My question is simply: Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?

**EDIT**; OK then, since it has been requested, here's the code:

**EDIT2**; After some trial and error, I've discovered that the magic number is 152. The script can store the first 151 pages, but when I change the number of pages to 152 suddenly the number of posts in my database table doubles to 304. Any ideas?

**EDIT3 (Good one)**: It turns out the script actually does what it's supposed to do on my local server. The problem comes when I run it on my web host server.

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// Initialize cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://data.riksdagen.se/anforandelista/?anflista=true&rm=&anftyp=Nej&d=&ts=&parti=sd&iid=&sz=1000&utformat=xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);

 // Some regex preg_match fun
 $regex = '/<anforande_url_xml>(.*?)<\/anforande_url_xml>/';
 $regex1 = '/<avsnittsrubrik>(.*?)<\/avsnittsrubrik>/';
 $regex2 = '/<anforande_url_xml>http:\/\/data.riksdagen.se\/anforande\/(.*?)<\/anforande_url_xml>/';
 $regex3 = '/<dok_datum>(.*?)<\/dok_datum>/';
 $regex4 = '/<talare>(.*?)<\/talare>/';
 preg_match_all($regex, $contents, $link);
 preg_match_all($regex1, $contents, $rubrik);
 preg_match_all($regex2, $contents, $id);
 preg_match_all($regex4, $contents, $talare);
 preg_match_all($regex3, $contents, $datum);

 // Display list of all posts
 $j = 0;
 echo "<pre>";
 foreach ($link[1] as $row) {
echo $j . " <a href=\"display.php?id=" . $id[1][$j] . "\">" . $rubrik[0][$j] . "</a>" . "<br />";
$j++;
 }

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

// Create array with all URLs
foreach ($link[1] as $row) {
$link[] = $row;
}

// Insert the core content to array
$lines = Array();
foreach ($link[1] as $row) {
$contents = file_get_contents($row);
$regex = '/<anforandetext>(.*?)<\/anforandetext>/s';
preg_match_all($regex, $contents, $output);

if (is_array($output) && isset($output[0]) && !empty($output[0])){
$lines[] = $output[1];  
}
}

// Connect. Yes, I know decprecated. Later issue.
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass") or die("Gick inte att ansluta.");
mysql_select_db("db");

// Insert into db
$h = 0;
foreach ($lines as $row) {
$utf_title = utf8_decode($rubrik[1][$h]);
$utf_speaker = utf8_decode($talare[1][$h]);
$utf_contents = utf8_decode($row[0]);
$date = utf8_decode($datum[1][$h]);

$query = "INSERT INTO riksdag (title, speaker, contents, date) VALUES('$utf_title', '$utf_speaker', '$utf_contents', '$date')";
mysql_query($query);
$h++;
}

echo "</pre>";

curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Have you used any tools to inspect the calls being made?  Perhaps observing the traffic you will see it loop.  Fiddler, burp, wireshark... any of those should work.  Or use a debugger or otherwise debug the code - should be able to tell which scenario you are experiencing.

Comment: How are the URLs to scan determined? Do you do something to prevent scanning same URL twice?

Comment: If the code was fine, there wouldn't be a problem. No, there's no magic repeats neither in browser, server or database. Provide the code so we could help.

Comment: I provided the code above. As you can see, it's a bit a complicated. That's why I wanted to stick to the principal issue. ficuscr, no I have never used any such tools. Should I?

Comment: It is unreliable to parse HTML with regular expressions.  See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html for why, and http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of the right way to do it in PHP.

Comment: If you've updated the max execution time in php.ini have you restarted Apache (assuming you're using Apache)? Can you shell into your server and run this PHP script locally, outside of the web server context, and see if it behaves as expected?

Comment: Andy: But is that was it causing the problem here? I'm sure there are better methods to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish but right now, I just want to fix the problem.

Comment: cfeduke: I'm using a remote server.

Comment: But, as I wrote above, the script works fine with fewer pages to fetch. Although, in phpmyadmin, it says "Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 150 total, Query took 0.0092 sec) [contents: [BLOB - 3.1 KIB] - [BLOB - 4 KIB]]". What is a BLOB?

Comment: Yeah...But I have no datatype set to BLOB.